# JPanel or JLabel seem to be creating two labels instead of one for each object?

Tags: java, swing, icons, jpanel, jlabel

Please excuse me if this is a very simple solution or stupid mistake - this is my first time attempting to implement graphics in Java! :)

I'm attempting to make a board of tiles, each is a Tile object, and all positions of the tiles are stored in a triple array of Tiles called 'content' (content[][][]).

In order to make each tile "clickable", I'm basically creating a label with each tile icon and positioning that tile on the board based on the Tile object's x,y coordinates. I do this for each of the non-null Tile objects in the content array.

This works fine when I use the graphics.drawImage function, but when I position each label using the setBorders() function it:

1. Creates the layout of tiles, but not perfectly - it seems some are missing or below others.

and

1. It creates a duplicate unpositioned layer above the other tiles that are in their sort-of correct positions.

The code for the function I'm calling is:

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics graphics) {
    // let superclass paint to fill in background
    super.paintComponent(graphics);
    Tile[][][] content = b.getContent();

    if (content==null || tileImages==null) {
        return;
    }

    /* Set dummy previous label */ 
    prevT.setBounds(-1,-1,1,1);

    // draw tiles back to front

    for (int i = 0; i<content.length; i++) {
        for (int y = 0; y<content[i].length; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x<content[i][y].length; x++) {
                final Tile t = content[i][y][x];
                if (t!=null) {
                    if (y>0 && content[i][y-1][x]!=null && t.equals(content[i][y-1][x])) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if (x>0 && content[i][y][x-1]!=null && t.equals(content[i][y][x-1])) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Image image = tileImages[t.getValue()][t.getSubindex()];

                    if (b.free(t)) {
                        image = tileImagesHL[t.getValue()][t.getSubindex()];

                    }

                    /* Mouse event magic */

                    graphics.drawImage(image, x*TILEW+TILEW/2+i*TILESKEW, (y+1)*TILEH/2-i*TILESKEW, null);

                    /* Create icon to be displayed */
                    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
                    /* Label that acts as the clickable tile */
                    final JLabel label = new JLabel();

                    /* Associate image with label */
                    label.setIcon(icon);

                    /* Allow mouse events to interact with label */
                    label.addMouseListener(this);

                    /* Position labels according to tile coordinates */
                    label.setBounds(x*TILEW+TILEW/2+i*TILESKEW, (y+1)*TILEH/2-i*TILESKEW, image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null));

                    /* Associate label with specified tile */
                    t.setLabel(label);

                    /* Add label to list*/
                    labels.add(label);

                    this.setVisible(true);
                    this.add(label);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any explanation for why this is happening would be greatly greatly appreciated! I've tried to re-write this function SO many times and am out of ideas!

Thank you! :)

Comment: just to emphaasize the most important bullet in @mKorbel's answer: dont change _any state_ of the component in paintComponent, it's for painting, nothing else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) don't create `Object` inside `paintComponent(Graphics graphics)`, prepare these `Object` before

my view, simple comtainer with Mouse event magic without `MouseListener`

2) create `JPanel` and put there `JButton#setBackground(someColor)`, and add `JButton#setRolloverIcon(someIcon)`, no longer any `MouseListener` needed

3) if you create Tiles then look for [GridLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

4) prepare `Icons` and add these `Icon` to the `JButton`, nothing else, any `Array` of `Objects`, no code more than I described

[image] [image: enter code here]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TilesWithButton {

    private Icon warningIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.warningIcon");
    private Icon infoIcon = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.informationIcon");
    private Icon errorIconRoll = UIManager.getIcon("OptionPane.errorIcon");
    private JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();

    public TilesWithButton() {
        myPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 1, 1));

        JButton btn = new JButton();
        btn.setBackground(Color.white);
        btn.setIcon(infoIcon);
        btn.setRolloverIcon(errorIconRoll);
        btn.setFocusPainted(false);
        myPanel.add(btn);

        JButton btn1 = new JButton();
        btn1.setBackground(Color.white);
        btn1.setIcon(warningIcon);
        btn1.setRolloverIcon(errorIconRoll);
        btn1.setFocusPainted(false);
        myPanel.add(btn1);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tiles");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(myPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(150, 100);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TilesWithButton tilesWithButton = new TilesWithButton();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @KristinaElise: Also consider the [MVC pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066590/gui-problem-after-rewriting-to-mvc/3072979#3072979).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I was able to solve it thanks to your answer :)